# Find $\alpha>0$ such that $\int_0^{\pi/2} \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)^{-\alpha}\tan x\,dx$ is finite

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find $\alpha>0$ such that the integral below

> $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)^{-\alpha}\tan x\,dx$$

is finite. I don't know how to begin, I need some help how to proceed.

Any help is very welcome.

**EDIT**

Following the comments of this post, I found $\alpha$ odd, but I'm not sure.

Comment: $\tan x$ diverges at $x\to\pi/2$. On the other hand, $\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)^{-\alpha}$ vanishes at $x\to\pi/2$. Their product will either vanish or diverge, depending on the value of $\alpha$. If $\alpha$ is large enough, the product will vanish, and this is what you're looking for. Can you think of a way to find what $\alpha$ is large enough?

Comment: @yohBS Thank you for your comment. My first thought was to solve this integral. I understand your comment but I don't have any idea how to find such $\alpha$

Comment: @yohBS I find $\alpha$ odd, am I right?